# Java equivalent of .NET constructs

Tags: java, .net

I've been writing .NET software for years but have started to dabble a bit in Java. While the syntax is similar the methodology is often different so I'm asking for a bit of help in these concept translations.

**Properties**

I know that properties are simply abstracted get_/set_ methods - the same in C#. But, what are the commonly accepted naming conventions? Do you use 'get_' with an underscode or just 'get' by itself.

**Constructors**

In C# the base constructor is called automatically. Is this also true in Java?

**Events**

Like properties, events in .NET are abstracted add_/remove_/fire_ methods that work on a Delegate object. Is there an equivalent in Java? If I want to use some sort of subscriber pattern do you simply define an interface with an Invoke/Run method and collect objects or is there some built-in support for this pattern?

**Update:** One more map:

**String Formatting**

Is there an equivalent to String.Format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Java from a C# developer's perspective](http://www.25hoursaday.com/csharpvsjava.html)

Dare Obasanjo has updated his original 10 year old article with a version 2: 
[C# from a Java Developer's Perspective v2.0](http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/2007/04/30/CFromAJavaDevelopersPerspectiveV20.aspx)

Although for you its the other way round :)

Comment: While giving a decent overview of the differences, that article contains some mistakes, especially concerning value types.

Comment: I imagine this was an interesting article at some point, but link rot appears to have rendered it useless now.  A shame you didn't copy/paste the most relevant points.  :(

Comment: updated URL to the same article on a different site. As you can see it would be rather uneconomical to copy paste the relevant points.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific questions:

**Properties**

By convention, Java uses "`get`" or "`set`" followed by the variable name in upper camel case.  For example, "`getUserIdentifier()`".  booleans often will use "`is`" instead of "`get`"

**Constructors**

In Java, superclass constructors are called first, descending down the type hierarchy.

**Events**

By convention (this is the one you'll get the least agreement on...different libraries do it slightly differently), Java uses methods named like "`addEventTypeListener(EventTypeListener listener)`" and "`removeEventTypeListener(EventTypeListener listener)`", where EventType is a semantic name for the type of event (like MouseClick for addMouseClickListener) and `EventTypeListener` is an interface (usually top-level) that defines the methods available on the receivers - obviously one or more of those references is essentially a "fire" method.

Additionally, there is usually an Event class defined (for example, "`MouseClickEvent`").  This event class contains the data about the event (perhaps x,y coordinates, etc) and is usually an argument to the "fire" methods.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a nice in depth comparison here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java

Comment: That page, while informative, does not answer his specific questions. It does not detail the behavior of java constructors or the conventions of java bean properties, and doesn't touch on event handling.

Answer (score 1):

A bean property in java is preceeded by a get followed by the bean name starting with a capital letter.  For instance the property 'color' would be associated with the methods 'getColor()' and 'setColor(int color)' (assuming the property is of type int).  There is a special case for boolean properties, the getter will be called 'is'... as in 'isWhite()', 'isBlack()'.  The setter remains the same.

When a class is created in java, all its parent class constructors are called in order, parents before children.

Events in Java are specific to a given event model, and not a core part of the language.  Examine the documentation for Swing or SWT for information on the event models of those GUI toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

[Sun's Code Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/) are a great reference for the Java way of doing and naming things.

Answer (score 0):

Property getters and setters can go by whichever naming convention you desire, or that your organization has standardized. A good naming convention is simply one that is common among those who will use/see it. That said, most in the Java community use 'getSomething/setSomething' as the naming convention on getters and setters.

Base constructors are called automatically, just like C#.